# subquery using IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
----------
User
----------
user_ID(pk)
UserEmail

----------
Employer1
----------
Emp1ID(pk)
Emp1NO

----------
Employer2
----------
Emp2ID(pk)
Emp2NO

----------
Project
----------
ProjEmpID
ProjEmpMGRID
```

I need to display User Email ID. The relation between the table goes like this:
In the Employer(1&2) table EmpID contains the value of UserID in the User table.

the Employer No relates to the values from the Project table.
EmpNo contains values from ProjEmpID, ProjEmpMGRID.

```
 select u.user_email from users u, Employer emp 
    where emp.Emp1ID =  u.user_id and 
    emp.Emp1NO IN
    (select ProjEmpID,ProjEmpMGRID from project)
union 
  select u.user_email from users u, Employer emp 
    where emp.Emp2ID =  u.user_id and 
    emp.Emp2NO IN
    (select ProjEmpID,ProjEmpMGRID from project)
```

but i get error in the subquery stating too many parameters on the IN clause.Is there any other way i could rewrite the query to get result. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Give example, I don't understand what you want to do, and rename your column, it is unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only return one column from your subquery.  If you just want both the employee ID and manager ID consider a union query as your subquery:

```
    emp.Emp2NO IN
(select ProjEmpID from project
 union
 select ProjEmpMGRID from project)
```

or rewriting to use two IN queries with separate subqueries for each.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Hauser is correct - you can't specify two columns in SELECT contained in an IN clause to one column outside.

That said, I re-wrote your query so you don't need to use UNIONs at all:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_email
  FROM USERS u
  JOIN EMPLOYER e ON u.user_id IN (e.emp1id, e.emp2id) 
  JOIN PROJECT p ON e.emp1no IN (p.projempid, p.projempmgrid)
                 OR e.emp2no IN (p.projempid, p.projempmgrid)
```

I also changed the query to use ANSI-92 JOIN syntax - your original uses ANSI-89.

Comment: The original joins are ANSI-92 compliant. Refer to section 7.5 'joined table', syntax rule number 1.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using the IN statement.  Use EXISTS instead.

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php

Example #1

Comment: I'm not familiar with the exact reasons, but it has something to do with, when using IN and a sub query the engine does a full table scan.  When using EXISTS it gets shortcutted and returns true at the first sign that the statement is true, I guess using EXISTS also allows indexes to be used.  I found this article, which explains the difference pretty well I believe.

http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5297080.html

Answer (score 0):

```
emp.Emp2NO IN
 (select ProjEmpID from project) or (select ProjEmpMGRID from project)
```

Hope you will understant why it should be so. u can put a mail to me at gnmsr@ap.nic.in

Ok i will expalin. Emp1NO is one value chcked with every value in the list of values return by a single column values where as ur query returns a matrix of many(no. of rows) X 2